# undeclared identifier SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE when building Apache Axis2/C

Tags: visual-studio, axis, winsock

I'm attempting to build Apache Axis2/C (actually I'm building the WSO2 WSF/C++ wrapper for it) and it keeps giving me an error when it comes across the symbol `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`.  It's a socket option, and MSDN says it should be available.  I'm using MSVC++ 6.0 on Win Server 2k3.  I don't have a choice about the compiler or the OS... if I was on linux, I'd be done already :P

I looked at a VS2005 installation and discovered that it contains the `#define` for that constant in winsock2.h.  It's not there in the winsock2.h that I have for MSVC6.  Also, in VS2005, it's under the PlatformSDK folder inside the VS2005 directory, whereas there doesn't appear to be any such directory on for MSVC6.  Why is this symbol missing?  How can I get it?  I'm tempted to just copy it across, but who knows what else I'll be missing down the road...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since Visual Studio .Net 2003, Microsoft change its way to deliver the PlatformSDK. It allows the C/C++ compiler to use PlatformSDK other than the bundled version with VC package.

You could install PlatformSDK for Windows Server 2k3, but The last SDK that will work with VC 6.0 is the February 2003 Edition which is not available from Microsoft website.

So you could simply copy the `#define` to your code before using `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`. It should work and support by Win2k3.